# Retrieve first value with Xquery using a wildcard

Tags: t-sql, xquery, wildcard

In an XmlData column in SQL Server 2008 that has no schema assigned to it, how can I pull the first item at a particular node level?  For example, I have:

```
SELECT 
XmlData.value('//*/*[1]','NVARCHAR(6)')
FROM table
where XmlData.Exist('//*/*[1]') = 1
```

I assume this does not work because if there are multiple nodes with different names at the 2nd level, the first of each of those could be returned (and the `value()` requires that a singleton be selected. 
Since I don't know what the names of any nodes will be, is there a way to always select whatever the first node is at the 2nd level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer by chaining Xquery `.query()` and `.value()`

```
XMLDATA.query('//*/*[1]').value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(6)')
```

This returns the value of the first node and works perfectly for my needs.